# How can I iterate over a xpath with two variables?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I try to iterate over the Xpath as follows:

```py
for i in range (1,9):
     xpath = '/ html / body / div / div / div / main / section / div 
              / div [2] / div / div [1] / div [2] /
              div [1] / table / tbody / tr [1] /td[{1}]'.format(i)

     element = driver.find_element_by_xpath (xpath) .get_attribute ('tabindex')
     print (element)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work that way and results in the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/marcel/PycharmProjects/AusarbeitungGetter/Ausarbeitung/Ausarbeitung/spiders/Getter.py", line 12, in 
>   xpath='/html/body/div/div/div/main/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[{1}]'.format(i)
>   IndexError: tuple index out of range

I would also like to know if I can iterate over two numbers so that I can use a variable for the last `td [i]` and for the last `tr [j]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're accessing index 1 not index 0 in the formatting . Use 0 between the brackets or just the brackets alone as it will default to the first input.

```
xpath = '/ html / body / div / div / div / main / section / div 
          / div [2] / div / div [1] / div [2] /
          div [1] / table / tbody / tr [1] /td[{0}]'.format(i)
```